# Get latest version of mPDF (7.1) to work with phpExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel, mpdf

I use mPDF v5.7.4 with phpExcel and it works, but that seems to be the newset version of mPDF that is compatible out of the box.

I include mPDF with these lines:

```
$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF;
$rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/mpdf';

if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
        $rendererName,
        $rendererLibraryPath
    )) {
    die(
        'NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
        '<br />' .
        'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure'
    );
}

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (PDF)
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="pdf.pdf"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF'); // $objPHPExcel is set before this whole code block
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

However [latest version (7.1)](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/releases/tag/v7.1.0) has a different file structure and I can't figure out how to include it, if even possible. Any ideas?

5.7.4 File Structure:

[image]

7.1 File Structure:

[image]